# {@tool snippet} is not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

While running `dartdoc` command flutter doesn't take `{@tool snippet}` how can I resolve this issue.

Here is the code snippet

````
// Title for the tab
///
/// {@tool sample}
///
/// Description
///
/// ```dart
/// Code snippet
/// ```
/// {@end-tool}
///
````